# Convert any string to url valid percent encoding in BigQuery

Tags: encoding, string-manipulation, google-bigquery

I am trying to convert any string with any set of special characters into a valid url of the format below.

In Bigquery

Example:

```
/artwork-v2/-̴̕ι-̶͔͛n̴e̷p̸u̴̒n̵uś̵̥o̵̙̾rt̷͗um̶̹͐-20380
```

encodes to:

```
/artwork-v2/-%CC%B4%CC%95%CE%B9-%CC%B6%CD%9B%CD%94n%CC%B4e%CC%B7p%CC%B8u%CC%B4%CC%92n%CC%B5us%CC%B5%CD%81%CC%A5o%CC%B5%CC%BE%CC%99rt%CC%B7%CD%97um%CC%B6%CD%90%CC%B9-20380
```